# Extract list' Id name using jQuery

Tags: jquery, list

I am using jQuery, and I need to extract the List' Id name.

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li id="outer1m"><a href="#url"><b class="">outer1</b></a></li>
    <li id="outer2m"><a href="#url"><b class="">outer2</b></a></li>

    <li id="outer3m"><a href="#url"><b class="">outer3  </b></a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li id="sub1"><a href="#url">inner1</a></li>
            <li id="sub2"><a href="#url">inner2</a></li>
            <li id="sub3"><a href="#url">inner3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li id="outer4m"><a href="#url"><b class="">outer4</b></a>
        <ul style="display: none;">
            <li id="sub8"><a href="#url"><i class="">inner4 </i></a></li>
            <li id="sub9"><a href="#url"><i class=""> inner5</i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

#### My code

```
$("li ").click(function()
{
    if ($(this).is("[id ^='sub']")) {
        var current_id=$(this).attr('id');
        alert(current_id);
    }
});
```

This code helps to alert the inner list, like sub1, sub2, etc. during a click. How do I alert the outer IDS?

On click, when I tried to check the above code to outer, it also alerts ths sub ID name. What would be an optimized procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is traverse up the parent() tree to the very last one -- here's how I would do that:

```
$("li").click(function(){
    if($(this).is("[id^='sub']")){
        var all_ul_parents = [];
        // get parents which are uls, and put each id in an array
        $(this).parents().filter('ul').each(function(){
            all_ul_parents.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        // the final one added will be highest level ul parent
        current_id = all_ul_parents.pop();
        alert(current_id);
    }   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var parent_id=$(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
```

It's ugly, but the only way I know of that will traverse up the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).parents('ul:last').attr('id')
```

Comment: This gives nav as result. onclick of 'outer1m' i need to  extract clicked ID